# Unable to install all updates due to one program's unmet dependacies

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dependencies, mate

I haven't touched my Ubuntu Mate machine in about 6 months. When I dust it off I find it has an update list a mile long. But it will not let me install them because one program "cqrlog" has unmet dependencies.
`sudo apt-get upgrade` returns:

```
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-fhTCNR/00-cqrlog_2.4.0-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I do not need the program anymore however `sudo apt-get purge cqrlog` and `sudo apt-get purge cqrlog-data` both return

```
    dpkg: error processing package cqrlog (--remove):
     package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
     reinstall it before attempting a removal
    dpkg: too many errors, stopping
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     cqrlog
    Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then tried `sudo apt-get reinstall cqrlog` which returned:

```
    ...
    dpkg: warning: old cqrlog package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cqrlog_2.4.0-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     new cqrlog package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     new cqrlog package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/cqrlog_2.4.0-3_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so any help you could give before I give up and distro hop again would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get remove cqrlog` work? Also, what version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: remove doesn't work either. I am running 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: You've not provided the actual full error messages; only final summaries of issues.  I'd suggest reading further up the error report(s) for clues; I'd also `sudo apt update` & peruse that output looking for clues (given you're using *focal* anything non-focal can create issues).

Answer (score 2):

In such a situation, you should ask APT for low-level package removal using

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all cqrlog-data
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all cqrlog
```

Then check for new software lists, install all updates by

```
sudo apt-get update # add any error output to the question
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and continue to use the system.